# How can i make css animation

Tags: html, css

i have 2 images, and one background:
(red and brown are images)
[image]

(white is background)

[image]

When i hover on first or second image it will slide to left/right side. Like a doors in shop. Slide both in same time (no only one).

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What coding have you tried that hasn't worked? Please post your existing effort so we can help you to improve your abilities.

Comment: Ya man if you've been an active member for a year you should know by now that folks would generally like to see some sort of a minimal attempt on your own first as opposed to just doing your work for you. We're here to help each other, but not be a free code service. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the accepted answer but it's a bit buggy (in firefox more so) if you put your cursor over the center and it bounces the sides back and forth and doesn't open. Personally I'd do something more like this.

[CODEPEN TO PLAY WITH](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/wJVNgo)

```css
#stage {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 15rem;
  background: green;
  border: black 1px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
}

#left-curtain, #right-curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#left-curtain {
  background: red;
  left: 0;
}

#right-curtain {
  background: blue;
  right: 0;
}

#stage:hover #left-curtain {
  left: -10rem;
}

#stage:hover #right-curtain {
  right: -10rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <span>PEEK - A - BOO!</span>
  <div id="left-curtain">Mouse</div>
  <div id="right-curtain">Over</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is so much better, but one problem is only that i need to change size of images (red/blue) like a one up answer. :P

Comment: It's just a concept example. Now that you have a starting place come on back with specific issues in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my quick and dirty solution. It's not perfect and perhaps someone else can fine tune it - but it works. Javascript/jQuery might allow you to come up with a more complete solution.

Hope this helps.

```css
.l,
.r {
  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
}

.l {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.r {
  background-color: brown;
  float: right;
}

.container:hover div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='l'>
  </div>
  <div class='r'>
  </div>
</div>
```